# Problem with HttpContext.Current.Cache and App Pool Recycles

Tags: asp.net, iis, caching

I have a web application that stores global data in the HttpContext.Current.Cache. I also have the application email me when cache items are reloaded. Since moving the application to IIS7 I'm getting a lot more cache reloads than I ever did in the past. I've double checked that my app pool settings are the same from IIS6 to 7, but still haven't been able to figure out what's causing this. I'd appreciate any thoughts on how to chase this issue down.

Pete

Comment: So it turns out that changing the pipeline mode from Integrated to Classic fixes the issue. I'm not 100% certain why this fixes the issue, but I'll update this issue as soon as I know why.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

[Application Pool Recycles from IIS 7 Setting Changes](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2008/08/11/application-pool-recycles-from-iis-7-setting-changes.aspx)